# C#: Shift given rows of jagged array to the top

Tags: c#, .net, shift, jagged-arrays

I make a tetris game where i need to clear lines. I collect the full rows and make them empty by doing:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < playingGrid.Length; i++) //get rows
    {
        if (!playingGrid[i].Contains(0)) //check if all colls are filled 
        {
            playingGrid[i] = new int[10]; //make the row empty
                                          //Here i need to push this row to the top of the jagged array

        }
    }
//playingGrid:
    public int[][] playingGrid = new int[20][];
  
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  {
    playingGrid[i] = new int[10];
  }
```

My question is how can i get the row that i cleared at the top of the jagged array?

Comment: This would matter what `playingGrid` is.

Comment: Could you please provide the full code for your grid?

Comment: oops sorry i forgot. My playingGrid is 20 x 10:
`public int[][] playingGrid = new int[20][];

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)

            {

                playingGrid[i] = new int[10];

            }
`

Comment: This isn't your ***full*** code. Also you cannot change a structure that you're iterating over.

Comment: Consider using a more flexible structure such as a `List<List<int>>`. Then you can just remove a row from the end and insert a clean one at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should play with indexes to move full rows. Also, no need to use `int` array as the cell (column) can have only 2 states which is the perfect case for using `bool`:

```
var rowsCount = 20;
var columnsInRowCount = 10;

var playingGrid = new bool[rowsCount][];

for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < playingGrid.Length; rowIndex++)
{
    playingGrid[rowIndex] = new bool[columnsInRowCount];
}

var rowIndexesToMove = new List<int>(rowsCount);
var firstNonEmptyRowIndex = Array.FindIndex(playingGrid, row => row.Contains(true));

// save full row indexes (start from first non-empty one, no need to check top empty rows)
for (var rowIndex = firstNonEmptyRowIndex; rowIndex < playingGrid.Length; rowIndex++)
{
    var row = playingGrid[rowIndex];

    if (!row.Contains(false))
    {
        rowIndexesToMove.Add(rowIndex);
    }
}

// move full rows to top
for (var fullRowIndex = 0; fullRowIndex < rowIndexesToMove.Count; fullRowIndex++)
{
    for (var rowIndex = rowIndexesToMove[fullRowIndex]; rowIndex >= firstNonEmptyRowIndex + fullRowIndex; rowIndex--)
    {
        for (var c = 0; c < playingGrid[firstNonEmptyRowIndex + fullRowIndex].Length; c++)
        {
            playingGrid[rowIndex][c] = false;
        }

        if (rowIndex > 0)
        {
            var temp = playingGrid[rowIndex];
            playingGrid[rowIndex] = playingGrid[rowIndex - 1];
            playingGrid[rowIndex - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx this helped me a lot